# Copy File from Windows Host to Linux [Python]

Tags: python, ftplib

What are the different modules/ways to copy file from a windows computer to a linux server available in python

I tried using ftplib api to connect to the windows server but i m unable to do with the error - socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

What are the other modules that i can connect to a windows computer to copy or list the files under a directory

Comment: It really depends on what kind of connectivity (i.e. servers / services) your linux server is offering (and what you're allowed to access) ...

Comment: @s-m-e a file is being generated on the windows computer (VPC) which i need to copy to my hone dir under the linux server , this is the basic idea behind the question. 

I can use winscp bhi the process is repeated arnd 5 times a day.

Comment: You mean you have ``ssh`` access to your Linux server?

Comment: @s-m-e yes I have the access to the linux server (on which i want to create a script) to copy the file from windows host to the home directory on linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to linux server, and the file generated on windows automatically, you can do the folowing:

1. Generate ssh-key on your windows maching
2. Add it to authorized_hosts of the linux machine
3. Install simple console scp tool on windows
4. Write simple cmd-script to copy file with help of scp, something like:

   scp c:\path\to\file.txt user@linuxhost.local:/home/user/file.txt
5. Run this script automatically every time, then the file is generated on windows host.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

This is the last resort i would opt for. I wanted to create a script on Linux side to fetch the file that is generated on windows.